# When pasting a link, I want the blank cells in the source worksheet to remain blank in the destination worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet consisting of a client (master) worksheet with monthly (clone) worksheets for workflow and task controls. The same client details are used on all the worksheets. If I add a new line or column in the master sheet, it also needs to add same on all the clone sheets. However, I do not want to have the blank cells in the master to display 0's in the clone sheets; they should remain blank in the clone sheets also. I've used the `Paste Link` function. How else can I update clone sheets from the master sheet without displaying 0's in blank cells from master sheet?

Comment: Equivalent question with many answers (a few of which are good): [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel](http://superuser.com/q/515932/150988).

Comment: Why not to use PowerQuery for making clones?

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is just *display* of blank cells as 0, then consider a custom format for the client sheet cells such as `#;-#;;@` (the third parameter is for `0` values) (of cource this will also display cells which actually contains `0`'s as blanks)

Answer (score 0):

go to file > options > advanced > "Display options for this worksheet:" {Your worksheet} >

> Click off "show a zero in cells that have zero value"

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, the problem is that Excel interprets incorrectly the `Empty` returned value of the `Variant` type. There is another approach if source data is under control: set the empty (blank) cells to formula `=""`. The `INDIRECT` Worksheet function correctly reproduces the mentioned error of the master and "replicated" worksheets. Here is the screenshot exemplifying the "foreground" (Excel active worksheet) and "background" (Watches window of VBA Editor with internals of that worksheet):

[image: Test Excel's interpretaition of an empty variant value]

As we see, the cell `A1` (`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, 1).Formula`) set formula `=""`, while `A2` (`ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(2, 1).Formula`) does not. As a result, formulas based on the `INDIRECT` Worksheet function (set `B1` and `B2` cells) show different value for the "same" input `""` (empty string). The input `""` is only look the same from Excel and Watches point of view. However, they are not the same indeed as we see when using debug-based "discovering" technics.

PS
I've used the described trick in one of my solutions, using formulas set with macros.